# Problem reading XML with SimpleXML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i've got an xml-string in $response that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RESPONSE>
  <ERROR>
    <ERROR_CODE>6</ERROR_CODE>
    <ERROR_TEXT>Authentication failed</ERROR_TEXT>
  </ERROR>
</RESPONSE>
```

In order to read it, I run

```
$xml_response = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

The problem is:

```
$xml_response->getName();
```

returns - as expected - "RESPONSE", but

```
isset($xml_response->RESPONSE->ERROR->ERROR_TEXT);
```

returns FALSE - but why? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$xml_response` *is* the root node. That's why you should call it `$RESPONSE` instead, to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without the root node when accessing the path that you want:

```
isset($xml_response->ERROR->ERROR_TEXT);
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem! Thanks a lot! :)